# Classpath in Java v3.141.59 in Eclipse 2019-03 not working

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am using *Eclipse 2019-03* with *Java Developer* installed with *Selenium Java Client Language Bindings V 3.141.59*.

But I get these errors:

```
'The type org.openqa.selenium.Webdriver is not accessable'
'The type org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Firefox.Driver is not accessable'
```

on each import statement, yet I've updated the project -> properties -> Java Build Path to pick up the selenium JAR files in the Classpath libraries as recommended.

I've tried running as admin, reinstalled Eclipse + Selenium bindings. Tried picking up other JARS but get same error. Tried checking permission on the Webdrivers directory - no issues there.

Answer (score 0):

For Standard implementation and avoid hard coded JAVA lib path, convert your project to Gradle or Maven and provide dependencies. This will make, maintenance easy avoid IDE dependencies.